# "Inverted" Selection Sort in Mathematica 8

Tags: sorting, wolfram-mathematica, selection

Well, I'm having trouble with this code, it's about writing the Selection Sort alghorithm in Mathematica, but inverted, I mean, instead of searching for the smallest number and place it in the first position of a list, I need to search for the biggest one and place it in the last position.
I've written this code but as I'm new to Mathematica, I can't find the solution. It doesn't sort the list. Thank you very much for reading, your answers will be helpfull!

```
      L = {};
n = Input["Input the size of the list (a number): "];
For[i = 1, i <= n, m = Input["Input a number to place in the list:"]; 
 L = Append[L, m]; i++]
SelectSort[L] := 
 Module[{n = 1, temp, xi = L, j}, While[n <= Length@L, temp = xi[[n]];
   For[j = n, j <= Length@L, j++, If[xi[[j]] < temp, temp = xi[[j]]];];
   xi[[n ;;]] = {temp}~Join~
     Delete[xi[[n ;;]], First@Position[xi[[n ;;]], temp]];
   n++;];
  xi]
Print[L]
```

Comment: José: ya hiciste 7 preguntas, no has aceptado ninguna respuesta y no has votado ni una sola vez. Te recomiendo que leas las FAQs del sitio. Con este comportamiento tus preguntas recibirán cada vez menos atención. BTW: You shouldn't use loops in Mathematica. It is designed as a functional, term rewiting system.

Comment: Gracias Belisarius, por ser un poco nuevo aqui no sabía mucho sobre lo de aceptar las respuestas pero empezaré a hacerlo, gracias!

Comment: Also check this sister site http://mathematica.stackexchange.com. Much better for Mathematica questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version.  In the `SelectSort[]` function I only had to change the function variable to a pattern variable, i.e. `L_`.  Other than that it seems to work.

```
(* Function definition *)
SelectSort[L_] := Module[{n = 1, temp, xi = L, j},
  While[n <= Length@L,
   temp = xi[[n]];
   For[j = n, j <= Length@L, j++,
    If[xi[[j]] < temp, temp = xi[[j]]];
    ];
   xi[[n ;;]] = {temp}~Join~
     Delete[xi[[n ;;]], First@Position[xi[[n ;;]], temp]];
   n++;];
  xi]

(* Run section *)
L = {};
n = Input["Input the size of the list (a number): "];
For[i = 1, i <= n, m = Input["Input a number to place in the list:"];
 L = Append[L, m]; i++]
SelectSort[L]
Print[L]
```

{3, 3, 5, 7, 8}

{8, 3, 5, 7, 3}

The output is first the sorted list from `SelectSort[L]`, then the original input list,`L`.